# How to prevent entire map from loading in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have a mapview with many annotations which loads when the user touches a button. The problem is that loading and populating the map with all the annotations already takes a long time. Is there a way to prevent unused areas of the map from loading in IOS? Is there a way to load only the part of the map that I am using on my App? 
Thanks

Comment: MKMapViews already do that. How many annotations are you trying to fit in the map?

Comment: over 600 annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more annotations you have the slower the map will be. I recommend either showing less annotations at a time or clustering annotations. Here are a few cocoapods that do annotation clustering

- https://github.com/choefele/CCHMapClusterController
- https://github.com/yinkou/OCMapView
- https://github.com/itsbonczek/kingpin

Comment: I have implemented annotation clustering, but it still takes up over 300mb of memory usage when I test it.

Comment: That is not necessarily a problem. If it runs fine on a phone that it should be fine.

Comment: Is there a way to Geofence only the portion of the map that I am using so that when the user navigates, or scroll around it doesn't load areas outside my App's boundaries which don't contain any annotations?

Comment: MKMapViews should already remove/hide annotations that not visible